# Is it possible to give a crew member "admin privileges"?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Me and my friend are together in a Crew.
Now he's away for 2 month in the holidays and doesn't have time to edit our crew stuff. He also doesn't know how to allow me, so that I can edit the crew stuff.

So it is possible to give another crew member "admin privileges"? If so, how can he give me these privileges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Your friend will need to promote you within the crew. Have him log in to social club, and go to the "Manage crew" tab. There, he can promote/demote members. At the commissioner level, you should be able to manage most everything in the crew that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, Just have him promote you to **commissioner** via Rockstar Games Social club, under manage crew (below is the breakdown of the all member level privilages).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]